# Question about composition of functions and their domains

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a doubt, please I hope you can help me.

Suppose I have $f(x)=\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}$. I know the domain of this function are $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$. So if I had $f(x-1)$ the function would be $f(x-1)=\dfrac{x}{x-2}$. And the domain of that function would be $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{2\}$.

My question is: Since my function $f$ had a domain where the $1$ was not, in the composite function $f(x-1)$ would not be that $1$ either
that is the domain would be $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Domain of composite function is intersection of domain of inner function and domain of the composition. Since your inner function is defined for all reals, the domain of composite function is $x \ne 2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The domain of a function is the set of all values where the function is defined. The domain of $f(x)$ is indeed $\{x| x\in\mathbb R, x\ne1\}$, since $x=1$ would make $x-1=0$. However, in the function $f(x-1)$ the domain is $\{x|x\in\mathbb R,x\ne 2\}$, because $x=2$ would make the denominator equal to zero. Because $x=1$ does not make the denominator zero in $f(x-1)$, it is part of the domain. Notice that the domain restrictions on a function do not necessarily carry over to a composite function.